# How can I install package in ActivePerl without Internet connection?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

In ActivePerl, "ppm" installs a package from the Internet, "ppm install x.ppd" installs from a ppd file, but most CPAN packages are distributed as *.tar.gz*

How do you supply modules to a machine running ActivePerl that doesn't have an Internet connection?  ("make" will probably not be available.)

Update: an Internet connection can be used to download files and transfer them to the machine with a USB key, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I am sure there is an easier way, but I just checked a ppd file and it is just an xml file ...

So you should be able to do the following if you want to install manually on a pc with no connection:

Open the file , ex

```
http://trouchelle.com/ppm/Acme-LOLCAT.ppd
```

and download the appropriate file pointed to in the CODEBASE tag, in this case:

```
http://trouchelle.com/ppm/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-5.8/Acme-LOLCAT-0.0.4.zip
```

Put both file on the pc with no connection, CODEBASE HREF="xxx" should be pointing to the zip file (either by putting the file in the same relative subfolder or by fixing the href so it points to the zip file on your disk)

Install from the ppd using

```
ppm install x.ppd
```

Comment: Having no internet connection is not the same thing as not being about to get the right files. In some situations, for instance, I update a minicpan on a thumb drive and carry that to the computer.

Comment: (1) The internet connection isn't available on the install machine, it is perfectly possible to use an internet connection to obtain files for transfer to that machine

(2) Getting PPD files to start with was the original problem - since most CPAN downloads were .tar.gz so we needed a different site

Answer (score 5):

See: http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#zip_files

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not an answer to your question, but if possible consider using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), a CPAN-friendly distribution of Perl for Windows.  It has a tidy installer, ships with make, a compiler and a properly configured CPAN shell all ready to go.

And then you can use something like [minicpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan) to create an offline CPAN repository.

Don't be a second class Perl citizen and have to wait for someone else to compile you a ppm, drink straight from the CPAN firehose!

Comment: This is easy to do with ActivePerl too.

http://www.openkomodo.com/blogs/troyt/ppm-install-mingw

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a very frequent scenario, I complete the answers here :

As far as ActivePerl 5.14 is concerned you can also download ".tar.gz" files for your platform, or download so-called ".ppmx" files (same format). Save the files and invoke the ppm installer later when offline :

```
ppm.bat install MIME-Lite-3.028.ppmx
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [A guide to installing modules for Win32](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=434813). It's a bit outdated (it talks about the command-line ppm) but the principles remain the same.